# What to do if member not defined?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this code:

```py
async def test_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MemberNotFound):
        await ctx.send(f'Member {member.name} not found!', delete_after=10)
        return
```

And when I write a command without mentioning a member, the console throws the error
`Member is not defined`.
How to fix it?

Comment: "how to fix it?" - don't use undefined symbols. In your case, `member`.

Comment: You are trying to access a variable, which is not defined, like the error message is already telling you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is in this code

```
await ctx.send(f'Member {member.name} not found!', delete_after=10)
```

You are trying to access variable that doesn' t exists in function (`member`).
I don't know other parts of your code, but i think you should pass member as another parameter

```
async def test_error(ctx, error, member):
```

Or if member is some global variable, add this.

```
async def test_error(ctx, error):
    global member
    # same as before....
```